# blueImp image upload, long delay before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, blueimp

When I select an image to upload, it takes up to 15 seconds for the interface/page to notice a change. Is there a way to update this interface before this happens? currently I'm using the `start` callback, but maybe there is something more appropriate.

```
start: function (e, data) {
    console.log($('._photo1 .progressholder'));
    $('._photo1 .progressholder').removeClass("remove");
    $('._photo1 .gal_Pic').addClass("remove");
}
```

I also tried:

```
add: function (e, data) {
    $('._photo1 .progressholder').removeClass("remove");
    $('._photo1 .gal_Pic').addClass("remove");
    data.submit();
},
```

and wile it is an improvement on subsequent loads, the first load still takes a while to respond